# Replacing square brackets content to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I try to change my code highlighting tags to match syntax highlighter from Alex Gorbatchev.

This is how my source code looks like:

```
[csharp]//awesome code[/csharp]
```

This is how it should look like:

```
<pre brush: csharp>//awesome code</pre>
```

I want to put the allowed tags into an array. So the pseudo code will be something like this:

```
$.each(allowedValues,function(index,value){
  MagicReplaceFunction(value);
}
```

So I need something to change my tags before I can call the methods from the code highlighter

jQuery is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replace` function.

```
> "[csharp]//awesome code[/csharp]".replace(/\[csharp\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/csharp\]/g, "<pre brush: csharp>$1</pre>")
'<pre brush: csharp>//awesome code</pre>'
```

`[\s\S]*?` Matches any space or non-space characters non-greedily. So,

- `\[csharp\]` Matches the starting `[csharp]` tag.
- `([\s\S]*?)` Captures any number of in-between characters.
- `\[\/csharp\]` Matches the closing `[/csharp]` tag.
- By replacing the matched characters with `<pre brush: csharp>` plus the characters inside group index 1 plus `</pre>` will give you the desired output.